# Dataframe for loops, if statements and append()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very particular set of logic I am attempting to implement into Python which is clearly beyond my current understanding.

I will outlay the concept in steps, then post the code attempts below:

1. Identify if the value within two separate columns qualifies (>= and <= 0.5) - if this is True then .append() the value of the third column (at the exact same Datetime index the test was passed) to a separate time Series object.
2. ELIF: identify if the value within the first two columns qualifies (<= and >= 0.5) - if this is True then .append() the value of the fourth column (at the exact same Datetime index the test was passed) to a separate time series object (the same one from the first test).
3. the final object is a separate time series object which holds values from column 3 and column 4 in chronological order from when each test was passed.

Here are the codes I have attempted thus far:

```
# create empty time series
port_switching = pd.Series([])

# attempt to define a function to switch returns
def switch(var1, var2, var3, var4):
    if var1 >= 0.5 and var2 =< 0.5:
        port_swtiching.append(cap_ret.last('D'))
    elif var1 <= 0.5 and var1 >= 0.5:
        port_switching.append(ew_ret.last('D')).

switch(df["var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"]
print(port_swtiching)
```

Now, I'm well aware of the faults of this code. I have received every error available in Python at this point. I'm just not sure how to bug fix. Can anyone offer ideas on how to move forward?
I would like to create a `for loop` thus to iterate over a much larger data set. Further, I don't necessarily need a function - whatever gets the logic through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the part you are seeking for is to make a `for` loop over all your rows and do some calculation based on the row, so I will not go through all your detailed process and just show the basic usage.

### Please take a look on `apply()`. [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

The `apply()` function can make you loop over along any axes.

You can easily write down your logic in a function (like `switch()` in the following example).

In this function, you can access your column value by dot operator. (like `row.var1`).

Here is a minimal example.

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'var1': [0.7, 0.5], 
     'var2': [0.6, 0.3],
     'var3': [3, 4],
     'var4': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def switch(row):
    if row.var1 >= 0.5 and row.var2 <= 0.5:
        return 'foo'
    elif row.var1 <= 0.5 and row.var1 >= 0.5:
        return 'bar'
    else:
        return 'baz'
    
port_switching = df.apply(switch, axis=1)
```

Comment: Wow! This is incredible. The final point of contention is returning the particular value of var3 or var4? I don't suppose "return var3.last()" would work because this would return the last value of the series. Possibly something like loc() could work given that I was able to save the particular index in a variable? Have any other ideas? - I will continue to test.

Comment: Hi @Toneloke, your explanation is still unclear. If you really need help, please explain the process detailedly and provide one or two examples.

Comment: @jardore801120 - I will ask another question on my profile so that I can use the coding capability.

Comment: @jardore801120 - I have posted the question! Hopefully, this allows for greater clarity.